# Battery backup not as long as expected and system temperature rises when using Ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, power-management, battery, acer, overheating

I'm using both windows 7 and ubuntu-13.04 in my acer aspire 5738g notebook.

I get 3 hrs battery backup in windows 7.

But in ubuntu it shows only 1.30 hours but as it goes on to ( it shows 1.30 but within 10 min it shows 1hr ) 0.59 hours suddenly it goes off.

Even though battery is fully charged and if I unplug the chord that time, the system will also go off.

It takes hardly 1 hour to get charge (in Win7), but in ubuntu it takes around 3 hours and the level will be fluctuating.

Also,the system heats up for short time use.
So please tell me how to come out from this 2 bugs.

You can email your suggestions to: raghugkatti@gmail.com