# Where to find all the power saving options Windows 10 provides?

Tags: dual-boot, power-management, 16.10, battery, windows-10

My Samsung Series 9 laptop holds around 2-3 times longer on battery when on Windows 10, compared to Ubuntu. At least part of it is due to extensive power saving options available on Windows (is there another part? would be nice to know)

Is there a utility or a set of utilities that would be equivalent to all these options?

[Windows power options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcDnE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the developers don't want to create any utility for Ubuntu. However, you can find some tips to improve the battery life for instance this one [How to improve battery life on Samsung 13.3” Series 7 Ultra (NP730U3E-S01AU)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482688/how-to-improve-battery-life-on-samsung-13-3-series-7-ultra-np730u3e-s01au)